# Windows OS compatibility for batch file needed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, operating-system, detect

I want to make a Batch file program, that can is compatible with Windows 10 and later. Not with older Windows systems.

Pseudocode:

```
if Win10+ then
[insert continued code here]
else
echo We're sorry, but the program you are trying to run isn't compatible with your Windows OS version.
echo Minimal requirement: Windows 10 (or later)
```

Please comment with the code if you have it.

I tried:

```
if "%version%" == "10.0" [continue the code]
else echo Not compatible
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) could use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)'s help:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "If ($([System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major) -GE '10') { Exit 0 } Else { Exit 1 }"
@If ErrorLevel 1 Exit /B
@Rem Your Win10+ code goes here.
```